# EF6 Code First Key not auto incrementing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have this class model:

```
public class Results
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Games Game { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResultItems> ResultItems { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason the Id field does not get set to auto increment as per the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Results] 
(
    [Id]     INT            NOT NULL,
    [GameId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Notes]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Results] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Results_dbo.Games_GameId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([GameId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Games] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_GameId] ON [dbo].[Results]([GameId] ASC);
```

I've also added:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Results>().HasKey(p => p.Id).Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

to my db context but still the migrations do not make this field auto increment. Can anyone see where I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Paul.

Comment: remove [Key], `DatabaseGenerated` is enough

Comment: The `Id` column in your `Results` table isn't defined as an `IDENTITY` - it should be `[Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL`

Comment: @marc_s I understand that I need the column defined correctly. My question is to why it's not been seeded correctly by code first migrations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sql server does not support alter column for add identity feature.
while your table are created , and you don't want loss your data , you cant do it automaticly,
back up your table,drop the column(ignore in EF),  and recreate your table or column with EF, abd restore your values

Comment: Thanks. This did work. In the end, I removed the table (no data yet) commented out all references to it in code. Added a migration and updated the database. Then added it back in and the column is auto incrementing as I would expect. I just wonder why it didn't set right in the first instance.

**Note:** I did have to remove any lines for the Results table from the migration after I removed the table as the migration failed because the Results table didn't exist.

Comment: @mordechai Thanks. Its perfect logic that helped me to explain to my boss. We tested it as you said and its unknown fact indeed.